# ral0 malfunctioning

Tags: wifi, openbsd

OpenBSD 4.9 using a ral card, RT2560

For some strange reason it stopped functioning, `ifconfig ral0` shows all the network information and network active, but no real connection. I keep getting DHCP requests and other built in tests repeating for the better part of 2-3 minutes before giving up.

It normally starts with "ral0 no link......"

I've tried rebooting, clearing the network information on `ifconfig`, and remaking the `hostname.ral0` file to no avail:

```
dhcp nwid (name) wpakey "(pass)"
```

Comment: [`pcidump(8)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pcidump&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386). [`dmesg(8)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dmesg&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) may also have the correct data, until the buffer wraps around anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get to that and update it when I get back, quick repair job.

Comment: Got it updated, RALink RT2560

Comment: What does your `hostname.ral0` file look like? `ifconfig(8)` output?

Comment: dhcp nwid (name) wpakey "(pass)"

Comment: How about `route(8)` and `ifconfig(8)` output? Can you `ping(1)` any hosts that might be on the same network or your gateway hosts?

Comment: Bizarre, it's suddenly working again.

ifconfig ral0 shows all the info for the network, ch11 43dB, ping hit the gateway and a few other computers I tested. Route shows no abnormalities in show mode.

Comment: @Lemur: Just a note to say that reading your question helped me set up wifi on an OpenBSD 5.1 configured netbook.  Thanks.